# Mule copies Maven dependencies into env.M2_REPO folder

Tags: maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.2 with Mule 3.8.1 runtime and Maven 3.3.9 and when I build my project, the Maven dependencies are written to a project folder called `${env.M2_REPO}` instead of my usual Maven repository `c:/users/my.name/.m2`.

[image]

How can I change it back to `c:/users/my.name/.m2` and stop this folder from being created?

It is causing errors to show in the Mule Problems tab saying "missing libraries" but when I move them from the `${env.M2_REPO}` folder to  `c:/users/my.name/.m2` the problems go away.

Comment: First off all it is not Mule 3.8.1, it is Anypoint studio IDE.

Comment: Search for this string `env.M2_REPO` in your workspace and see where you're setting this up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that in the settings.xml file in the Maven application folder, the default repository was set to env.M2_REPO instead of the .m2 location.  Changed it to .m2 and all working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> right click on project--> Java Build Path-->Add Variable --> configure
>   variables--> Classpath variables--> new

-----------OR---------------

> preferences-->Java--> Build path--> classpath variables

```
name: M2_REPO
path: location of repo
```

**Update1:**
right click on project, you will see something like this.
first time click on

> populate maven repository

..
If your problem still didn't fixed then click on

> Update project dependencies

.. This is how it fixed my problem few months back.
[image]

Comment: M2_REPO looks to be populated with c:/users/my.name/.m2 which is what I should see when I follow your suggestions above, but when I build the project all of the downloaded dependencies end up in ${env.M2_REPO} folder that appears in the package explorer panel (see screenshot above)

Comment: When I run update project dependencies, it is at this point where it creates the {env.M2_REPO} folder and places the dependencies inside there.  The classpath variable point to c:/users/my.name/.m2 so not sure why it is creating and downloading the dependencies to {env.M2_REPO}.  Just need to find out where I can stop it from doing this.

Comment: try creating sample example project from anypoint and compare pom and classpath file to see what is wrong with you project.